# Looping edge case issues

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

Sorry if the question seems trivial but I'm very frustrated with it right now - I can't seem to figure it out.

I have an arraylist called `SmallerVals` which contains `[ab,ab'c, abce']`
I want to use an iterative mechanism (for loops) to print `yes` for the number of characters in the arraylist that have no negation, and print `no` for characters that do.

For example, the code should give an output

> Yes Yes Yes No Yes Yes Yes Yes No.

My code seems to be skipping one `Yes`. I hope you guys can help me out. Thanks!

Code here :

```
for(int i = 0; i < SmallerVals.size(); i++) {
    vals = SmallerVals.get(i);
    for(int j = 1; j<(vals.length();j++) { 
        if(Character.isLetter(vals.charAt(j))) {
            if((j+1)<=vals.length() 
               &&((j+1)!=vals.length())
               && ((vals.charAt(j+1)!= '\''))) {
                    System.out.println("Yes");
            }
        }
        if(vals.charAt(j)=='\'') {
            System.out.println("No");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain what "negation" is?

Comment: i think its the ' he is talking about.

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad negation is b' in ab'c

Comment: So you want "Yes" if it's a letter and "No" if it's " ' ", correct?

Comment: No, it should be Yes if its just a character, and No if its a character followed by " ' ". For example ab'c should give Yes No Yes

Comment: what is your current output?

Comment: Please can you add more variables in your code (ex: String smallerVal = SmallerVals.get(i); ), if possible with meaningful names? You may find the answer to your question yourself once you have cleaned your code.

Comment: @Volune Hope that's better. Sorry for the mess.

Comment: Does list contain strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you use a nested `for-loop` to scan the Strings (Assuming there are no empty strings):

```
for(int i = 0; i < SmallerVals.size(); i++) {
    String val = SmallerVals.get(i);

    for(int j = 0 ; j < val.length() ; j++) { 
        if(j == val.length()-1) {
            System.out.println("Yes");
            break;
        }

        if( Character.isLetter(val.charAt(j)) && val.charAt(j+1) != '\'' ) {
            System.out.println("Yes");
        } else {
            System.out.println("No");
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you understood what I meant, your code basically prints Yes for an alphabet and no otherwise. That seems simple. I want something where the code prints No for the character if it is followed by a negation for example b' should be No. Not, Yes No.

Comment: @TusharSharma I misunderstood, your phrasing was confusing. Here I updated the code

Comment: It still seems to have issues - try this ArrayList [ab', ab, abce']. The output should be : Yes No Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes No

Comment: @TusharSharma Oh I see, the `ArrayList` contains 1 element: `"[ab', ab, abce']"`, I thought you meant it contained 3 elements `ab'`, `ab` and `abce'`. Is that what you meant?

Comment: No, you thought right, it contains 3 elements. ab', ab and abce'. Your code isn't giving me the output I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: @TusharSharma, oops, I put the increment `j++` in the wrong `if` block

Comment: It is still incorrect. I suggest you check the outputs I have mentioned before commenting as I don't want this section to be spammed. Thanks :)

Comment: It doesn't work for the first element being 2 characters long without negation. Eg. ab does not give yes yes.

Comment: There, sorry I kept making off by one mistakes